# mlogit resulting in "system is computationally singular" error when using categorical independent variables

Tags: r

I am using R x64 3.1.1 in R Studio and have been having trouble trying to develop a multinomial logit model using mlogit with a rather large data set contain both categorical and numeric IV.  The model is using land cover data from satellite imagery (independent variable) to predict the land use (dependent variable).  These data are for plots across North Carolina.

When I had run the mlogit for the full model I recieve:
 "Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.6507e-131"

I have scoured through all the questions in this forum and read up up on the concept of singularity, but have not found one that addresses the situation when there the IV is categorical, nor do I know what to do to address the problem.

Through an iterative process, I believe I have narrowed down the dependent variable that may be causing the singularity issue but 1) am not sure, and 2) not sure I know what to do about it.  It is a categorical variable for the actual land cover and I cannot leave it out of the model.

Here is the base code with the just the DV (lu.srs.c4.age)  and the IV (lc1):

```
set.seed(12976)
library(mlogit)

ncdat<-dget("ncdat")
str(ncdat)
table(ncdat$lu_srs_c4_age, ncdat$lc1)

#REGRESSION OF lu_srs_c4_age VS lc1
lu4.log <- mlogit(lu_srs_c4_age ~ 1 | lc1,data=ncdat, shape="wide", 
                  reflevel="developed_no_age_given")
summary(lu4.log)
```

Here is the table:

```
agri/pasture barren developed emerge wetland forest grass/herb shrub water
  ag_range_no_age_given              2612      2       197             12    277        100    74     8
  cover_unk_no_age_given                6      1         2              5    165          1     2     0
  developed_no_age_given              445     21      1136              7    410        134    76     7
  oth_for_closed                        0      0         0              5     29          0     0     0
  oth_for_neg_age                       0      0         0              0      6          0     0     0
  oth_for_new                           0      0         0              0      2          0     0     0
  oth_for_sapling                       0      0         0              1      4          0     0     0
  oth_for_seedling                      0      0         0              3      4          0     0     0
  timber_closed                       108      3       186             50   6598        124   262    10
  timber_neg_age                        3      0         1              1     28          6     6     0
  timber_new                            1      0         1              2     27          7     3     0
  timber_sapling                       55      5        16             15    612         45   158     3
  timber_seedling                      48      4        17             34    265        125   144     0
  water_no_age_given                    4     22        11             21     45          6     5  1431
  wetland_beach_no_age_given            1      5         2            108     18          3     0    14
```

My apologies for not getting this line up correctly - I did not see any way of entering the table other than the code snippet tool.  The Land Cover Categories for lc1 are: 1) agri/pasture, 2) barren, 3) developed, 4) emerge wetland, 5)forest, 6) grass/herb, 7) shrub, and 8)water.

If someone could walk me through how to correctly load a table for viewing and also how to upload up the data file to accompany this question so someone can run the file I would be much obliged.

I understand that anyone cannot properly answer the question until they can get the data and run the code but perhaps there may be something in the table that may could offer some explanation athat could lead to my successful use of this data.

Comment: Looks like you have too many zeros to estimate all those parameters. Are you sure you didn't want the formula: `lu_srs_c4_age ~ lc1` instead? If you are unsure exactly what you should be modeling, you might want to get statistics help from [stats.se] instead.

Comment: good idea - will look into it - thanks - jaj